# amule, Fedora 14, iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to set  iptables rules for aMule, but I am not sure which one are the right ones. 
Googling around, I have seen something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4662 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 4672 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

but I am not sure whether they are fine/complete.
Instructions by somebody who knows better than me is very welcome.
I am on Fedora14
thks

UPDATE:
I am not able to save these configurations. It seems they are gone, when i shutdown.
Please, teach me! thks

Comment: add port "4665" and make sure the router forwards the ports as well. you should be fine.

Comment: UPDATE: I am not able to save these configurations. It seems they are gone, when i shutdown. Please, teach me! thks

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the changes permanent you need to save your current state doing:

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

also, its generally a good idea to back up your oldie `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

to apply the newly changes:

```
systemctl restart iptables.service
```